# Isekai manhwa with a white-haired, purple-eyed female lead and a black-haired male lead made from mana stones

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I only read the first chapters, but both of the main characters were made from mana stones and are locked in the magic tower until the mage they were made for gets them.

The male lead's name was Cal or Carl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[I Will Rewrite the Dead End Novel](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-will-rewrite-the-dead-end-novel)***...?

> Yes, I possessed someone, but I can't remember at all who I was in my previous life. All I remember is just this guy's face before my eyes. We were together the day I opened my eyes for the first time as one of the many test subjects of the Magic Tower wizard's experiment. And strangely enough, this guy seems to know more about my previous life than I do. This is the world of a novel, a tragic novel with only pain and misery for every single character, where the only one I can trust and rely on for survival is myself, I have to run away from this guy who, in the future, will kill the female lead's entire family. He is a psychopath seeking the destruction of this world. And finally, I managed to escape his grasp and thought I could live a peaceful life.
>
> [image: Promotional image for "I Will Rewrite the Dead End Novel," depicting the characters, Yul and Kal.]

The protagonist, a white-haired, purple-eyed young woman named Yul, is a minor character in the world of a novel set in a magic empire. She became aware that she was a character in a novel a few years earlier, and knows the plot of the novel, including future events, but has no memory of her previous life.

In this world, wizards normally live longer than ordinary humans, but there's a disease that can kill them instantly if their mana is depleted. As a solution, they come up with the idea of using magic to create people to serve as living mana stores for them. Each "black magic test subject" is created from the mana stone of a specific person, so they can later be paired with that person when that person reaches adulthood and registers with the wizard's association.

Yul was created from the mana stone of the Heroine of the novel, Estella Demetrice, as was Kal, a black-haired young man who's due to become the antagonist of the novel, according to the original plot. They've both spent their lives as prisoners within a magic tower run by a master and his subordinates. Estella eventually visits the tower and is asked to choose either Yul or Kal to be her pair.